# How to select record in the database using BETWEEN in sql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, momentjs

How to select record in the database using BETWEEN in sql? what I want here is to select record within the startDate and endDate. if the record is exists within the range of startDate and endDate it will return true and if not it will return false

//form

```
formData = {
    "startDate": "14/04/2022 09:41 PM",
    "duration": 3600000,
    "assignedTo": "441017201|441017210",
}
```

// current code

```
var hasExistingEvent = (assignedTo, startDate, end) => {
    var assigne = assignedTo.split("|")
    var userFilters = assigne.map((user) => {
        return `Assigned_To_Ids LIKE '%${user}%'`;
    }).join(" OR ");
    return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        .....,("SELECT Assigned_To_Ids, startDate FROM Event WHERE ("+ userFilters +") AND (startDate BETWEEN '" + moment(startDate).format() + "' AND '"+ moment(end).format() + "')", 100, function(data){
            return resolve(data.length ==0)
        })
    })
}

var validatedUserExistsEvent = async(formData) => {
    var {  assignedTo, startDate, duration } = formData
    var dd_startDate = moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:m A').toDate()
    var end = new Date(dd_startDate);
        end = new Date(end.setTime(end.getTime() + duration));
    var hasExisting = await _data.hasExistingEvent(assignedTo, dd_startDate, end);
    return hasExisting;
}
```

record from database

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve here. Seems like you want to display a bar chart? Can you simplify the problem by just showing a minimum working example of the `kendoChart` bit? Seems like your mapping of `counts` and `parents` are wrong.

Comment: Also, what is `_UI` ?

Comment: Show us the `SELECT` _after_ it is constructed.  That we can discuss what the `BETWEEN`.  It may be some trivial problem with the formatting.

Comment: What data type are the dates in your table? They look like text...

Answer (score 1):

SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;

So basically:
You select the column names that you want from the table. Where the column that contains your date is between startDate and endDate.

Answer (score 0):

you can create sp for this operation or use sql command like this

```
select case when exists (select * from Ls2 where date between @startdate and @EndDate) then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example, Below query fetch data between March 1 to March 30 2022 using Between.

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN startDate BETWEEN '2022-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-03-31 23:59:59';

If your table has data satisfying this condition, there will be some rows in array otherwise it will be empty.

So based on that, you can set your variable as true and false.

Answer (score 0):

METHOD 1:
In case if you want to get result as true or false on the basis of SQL condition, then you can use SELECT CASE of sql

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS 
  (
        SELECT Assigned_To_Ids 
        FROM events 
        WHERE startDate BETWEEN someStartDate and someEndDate 
  )
  THEN 'TRUE'
  ELSE 'FALSE'
```

END

here someStartDate, someEndDate are variables which you can replace accordingly.

METHOD 2:

You can write sql query to return 0 or positive value depending on whether records are present or not afterwards with simple check in function you can return the value as true or false. In that case sql query will be

```
SELECT count(Assigned_To_Ids) 
FROM events 
WHERE startDate BETWEEN someStartDate and someEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM events WHERE startDate BETWEEN @startDate and @enddate
)
THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure what's going on, but I'm guessing you are looking for this:

```js
`SELECT Assigned_To_Ids, startDate 
FROM Event
WHERE ${userFilters} 
AND (
  startDate < ${moment(startDate).format()}
  AND startDate > ${moment(end).format()}
)`
```